# woocommerce login/registration button points to wrong page

Tags: authentication, woocommerce

i have on my theme the Customer login/registration button as bellow.

[image: login/registration button]

my issue is that on selection of the button it forward me to a page that does not exist. how can i update this button destination page to point to the correct login/registration page?

thanks

Comment: "i have on my theme". Which theme are you using? is your "my account" page declared correctly on WC Settings?

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of search i notice that on woocommerce settings there was the account but the login account page. i have update it and the issue is resolved.

thanks